# Logging to Sentry in Android with extra info

Tags: java, android, log4j, sentry, raven

I have logging working to Sentry from android just using the EventBuilder from [raven-java](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java), but I need to attach extra info which apparently EventBuilder or java.util.logging can't do.
I tried to use log4j but it doesn't pick up log4j.properties, how can I configure it with the Sentry DSN and other information? I have no preference about what logging library to use, so logback or log4j2 will do but they seem to suffer from the same problems.

I tried to configure logging programmatically but can't add the appender SentryAppender.

I also tried using [android-logging-log4j](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/) library but this has the same problem.

I realize that https://github.com/joshdholtz/Sentry-Android exists which might work but it doesn't do retries in case of network issues which is quite important.

Comment: Hi eggbert. I am the author of the Senty-Android client you have linked. There is currently an issue to solve the offline/retries that are you mentioning - https://github.com/joshdholtz/Sentry-Android/issues/7. I am actually in the middling of closing that issue right now. I know this doesn't solve your issue right now but I will comment back here when that issue is closed :)

Comment: Hi, I did notice the open issue and a branch which seemed to be trying to save events. I will give the pre-release a go, I much prefer your library to the 6 libraries I have to install just to get raven-java working. I was thinking of using SharedPreferences to store events but maybe files is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The https://github.com/joshdholtz/Sentry-Android library now supports saving of offline captures and failed captures as of version v1.1.0 - https://github.com/joshdholtz/Sentry-Android/releases/tag/v1.1.0